# Jenkins 'Build Now' fails, looking for CMakeLists.txt in the wrong directory

Tags: jenkins, cmake

New to Jenkins, and I am having trouble with my current project build.

When I hit the Build now button I get the following error.

`CMake Error: The source directory "/dir1/dir2/jenkins/jobs/Project/workspace/Project" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.`

The CMakeLists.txt that is looking for is in the "workspace" directory, why is Jenkins looking in the "/Project/workspace/**Projects**" directory?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! How did your CMakeLists.txt file get in the `workspace` directory? A CMakeLists.txt file is *specific to* a given project, so it should be located within the `workspace/Project` folder. See the example [here](https://www.codepool.biz/building-cmake-project-jenkins-windows.html).

Comment: @squareskittles I may be confusing myself a little more. I have a CMakeLists.txt file in the repo of the project I am trying to build. This was created by the dev team. 

I did just notice that jenkins made cmake directory. I have a lot I need to learn.

I appreciate your help.